# Custom Post Type - Append post slug to current URL

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, custom-post-type, permalinks

I've registered a custom post type `portfolio`.

```
register_post_type( 'portfolio',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' =>  __('Portfolio', THEMENAME),
                'singular_name' => __('Portfolio', THEMENAME),
                ),
            'public' => true,
            'supports' => array('title','editor','thumbnail'),

        )
    );
```

I also have a Page Template that list all the `portfolio` items with title *My Works*. The URL of the page that uses the template is:

*http://sitename/my-works*

However when I create a portfolio post I get a URL like this:

*http://sitename/portfolio/post-name*

Is it possible when an item in the Page Template is clicked for it to redirect to:

*http://sitename/my-works/post-name*

I have a feeling that this have something to do with the `rewrite` argument?

Answer (score 0):

1. Set the  permalinks to `/%postname%/`
2. You need to set the rewrite like this:

'rewrite'         => array(
'slug'          => ''
),

Comment: I select *Custom Structure* and write there `/%postname%/` and it selects *Post name* automatically. Is this the way that it should be?
My links are still with */portfolio/* in them

Comment: I visited Pemalinks a couple of times to flush everything but stil no. Anyone? :(